# How to ensure order in aggregation in Spark Dataset?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm dealing with a dataset containing some data with timestamps, and I need to group it by an ID and a time window. After grouping, I need to perform a custom aggregation that only makes sense if it is performed in order (specifically, ordered by the timestamps). So far, what I've done is just calling `groupBy` and `agg` with my `udaf`:

```
ds.groupBy($"id", window($"timestamp", "1 day", "1 day", "8 hours") as "timeslot")
  .agg(myUDAF($"someCol", $"someCol2") as "result")
```

But even if the original Dataset is in order, there is no guarantee that it will be processed in that same order after all parallelization takes place, right?

More specifically, when implementing a custom `Aggregator` (from `org.apache.spark.sql.expressions`), a `reduce` and a `merge` method must be defined, whose signatures are `reduce(buffer: BUF, data: IN): BUF` and `merge(a: BUF, b: BUF): BUF`. How can I guarantee that input data for `reduce` always follows an order, and `merge` buffers also respect that order (i.e., buffer `a` contains aggregated data from rows that come before the rows from buffer `b`)?

Comment: I'm not sure if it would work, but can you try `.sortWithinPartitions($"timestamp")` before grouping?

Comment: @Kombajnzbożowy that would ensure the order for rows in the same partition, but there is no guarantee that two merge buffers (as explained in the updated question) would respect that order, since they could be from different partitions.